# Missing parameter client_id?? Ruby RestClient issues

Tags: ruby, rest-client

I'm using RestClient to work with the Spotify API (but I'm assuming this is a general issue, not specifically spotify).

The API requires passing client_id. My code:
authorization = Base64.strict_encode64 "#{@clientID}:#{@clientSecret}"
begin

```
request_body = { response_type: 'code', client_id: @clientID, redirect_uri: REDIRECT_URI }
#response = RestClient.get(AUTHORIZE_URI, request_body)
puts response = RestClient::Request.execute(method: :get, url: AUTHORIZE_URI, payload: request_body)
```

rescue RestClient::BadRequest => e
    puts e.response
end

But I'm getting a BadRequest exception, and the response states "Missing required parameter: client_id".

If I do a curl:

```
puts `curl -I -s -X GET "#{AUTHORIZE_URI}?client_id=#{@clientID}&response_type=code&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI"`
```

I get a normal, 200 OK response. What is going on here????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use `params` key inside `headers` hash to pass query parameters. Documentation below

> Due to unfortunate choices in the original API, the params used to
>   populate the query string are actually taken out of the headers hash.
>   So if you want to pass both the params hash and more complex options,
>   use the special key :params in the headers hash. This design may
>   change in a future major release.

```
RestClient::Request.execute(method: :get, 
                            url: 'http://example.com/resource',
                            timeout: 10, 
                            headers: {params: {foo: 'bar'}}
                           )

 ➔ GET http://example.com/resource?foo=bar
```